# Last n weekdays in sql where clausel

Tags: mysql, timestamp, period

We are using MySQL as our database to store messages with timestamps. Is it possible to create a query that returns messages of the last n weekdays?

I.e. if n is 4 and today is Tuesday, I want messages from this weeks Monday, last weeks Friday, last weeks Thursday and last weeks Wednesday .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this directly with mysql it would be a little complicated. As Vatev recommended you should calculate date star date in advance, but if you really want to do this, you'll probably need following functions:

- [`ADD_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), with `INTERVAL -N WEEKS`
- [`FLOOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor), in C `int/int` would do just fine
- [`MOD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod), `a % b` :)
- [`WEEKDAY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

First of all you need should count how many weeks you should go back, that's easy... For you `one week = 5 days`, that means

```
weeks = FLOOR(days / 5)
```

We've taken care of weeks, so we'll now have to work with the rest:

```
rest = days MOD 5
```

Now we have two cases, weekend has occurred or no, for the case that there wasn't weekend days are good. We have to add 2 days to skip it. The weekend occurred if `(WEEKDAY(now) - rest) < 0`

```
rest = IF( (WEEKDAY(now) - rest) < 0, rest + 2, rest)
```

And now we can build it to one par (let's assume you have `{days}` and `{rest}` pre-calculated):

```
WHERE date >= ADD_DATE(
    ADD_DATE (
        {now},
        INTERVAL -IF( (WEEKDAY({now}) - {rest}) < 0, {rest} + 2, {rest}) DAYS, 
    ),
    INTERVAL -FLOOR({days} / 5) WEEKS
)
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. As Vatev pointed out, I think I will calculate the starting day in my application to put some stress from the db.

Comment: Stress on the DB from this operation will be negligible, but there will probably be a lot less stress for you if you do it in a more sane language :P

Comment: @Thomas I wrote it so I'll be reusable for any other language, especially PHP accepts (in [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) ) intervals to and the logic is the same. You can even do `timestamp() - weeks*7days*24hour*3600seconds` to save some little resources.

Answer (score 1):

The best i can come up with is calculating the start date ({start_date} in the query) in the language of your choice and then running something like this:

```
SELECT some_things
FROM your_table
WHERE 
    WEEKDAY(time_column) < 5
    AND time_column >= {start_date}
ORDER BY time_column DESC
```

You can also make a stored function to calculate 'the date x week days ago' and use it for {start_date}.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT columns 
FROM table
WHERE datediff(column_with_timestamp,NOW()) > n
```

Where N is as you defined above, the number of days you're looking for.

Comment: Week days, not including weekends.

Answer (score 0):

```
COL >= date_sub( NOW(), interval 1 week) and
weekday( COL ) < 5
```

- date_sub is to seek rows created last week
- weekday is to exclude sunday or saturday